# Reload a specific controller after Ajax Call

Tags: symfony

### I have embed a controller in a template:

```
{% render "AcmeUserBundle:User:showUsersList"} %}

<a onClick="changeStatus({{user.getUserId()}})"
```

The aim is simple:

- The user clicks on the link which updates the status via ajax (this works fine)
- Reload the embedded controller only, not the entire page!

At the moment, I managed to do this, by reloading the entire page using `document.location.reload(true);` This has no point so far...

### Here is the ajax part:

```
//...
function changeStatus(userId){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxControllerPath,
        data: "userId="+userId,
        success: function(){
            document.location.reload(true); 
        }
    });  
}
```

### How would you reload the embedded controller only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the ajax controller, this controller could render the showUsersList template and return the generated html as a json object:

```
$answer['html'] = $this->forward('AcmeUserBundle:User:showUsersList')->getContent(); 
$response = new Response();                                                
$response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
$response->setContent(json_encode($answer));
return $response
```

Then in your javascript use this generated html to replace the content of the controller part of the page (use a div or similar to identify it)

```
<div id="changethis">{% render "AcmeUserBundle:User:showUsersList"} %}</div>

function changeStatus(userId){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxControllerPath,
        data: "userId="+userId,
        success: function(returnData){
            $('#changethis').html(returnData['html']);
        }
    });  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Carlos. That looks good. There is an error in render() as render can only render a template within a controller:$answer['html'] = $this->render("AcmeUserBundle:User:showUsersList.html.twig"); This is not working yet.

Answer (score 3):

This is working so far:

Embed the controller within a div:

```
<div id="block1">
    <a onClick="changeStatus({{user.getUserId()}})"
</div>
```

And reload the controller using javascript at the end of the ajax call

```
$('#block1').load("{{ path('show_users_list') }}");
```

Does anyone have a better suggestion?